# 1H NMR impurity peaks don't align across samples

Tags: nmr-spectroscopy

I have a series of four 1H NMR spectra for a polymer I'm synthesizing under different reaction conditions. However, the acetone and chloroform peaks are shifted relative to each other across the samples - see the attached images, where if the spectra are calibrated to the chloroform peak, the acetone peaks do not overlap.

I'm relatively a novice at NMR, so I apologize if the answer is obvious, but what could be causing something like this? Is it a common observation?

[image: chloroform]
[image: acetone]

Comment: Can your polymer have some interaction with acetone? Through hydrogen bonding or so?

Comment: Looks like your peaks at 7.2 are moving also. The acetone peaks appear to be  quite different concentrations - are these plotted to the same y-scale? The top acetone trace looks to be a much larger integral than the bottom trace. Concentration influences chemical shift significantly.

Comment: Could it just be that the NMR did not get recalibrated to the standard and you measured these samples on different days?

Comment: That is why TMS is (was) recommended

Comment: @RaoulKessels - yes, there are hydroxyl groups on the end of the polymer.

Comment: @long - these are not on the same y-scale. The acetone is also from washing the tubes, so I wouldn't expect the concentrations to be well-controlled. I've since re-done these spectra with cleaner tubes and the acetone peaks are gone, so this isn't of much concern beyond calibrating the spectrum. The CHCl3 peak is from the solvent, which is CDCl3.

Comment: @jheindel these were all measured consecutively. If there was a 'hardware' calibration error, wouldn't we expect the peaks to shift the same amount, such that using the CHCl3 peak as a reference would also align the acetone peaks?